# Structs and Unions

Tags: c++, struct, unions

```
struct X { const int n; };
union U { X x; float f; };

void tong() {
    U u = {{ 1 }};
    u.f = 5.f; 
    X *p = new (&u.x) X {2};
}
```

What does `{{}}` do?
Is there need for writing - `(&u.x)`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Comment: `{{1}}` is a constant initializer for the union containing a struct. The outer `{}` represent the union, and the inner `{}` represent the struct. So the `1` inside of `{{1}}` is setting `n` to 1.

Comment: @lurker I'd put it in an answer. It's exactly what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

`new (&u.x) X {2}` is a "placement new" syntax. It doesn't allocate a memory and use existing address `&u.x`.

You can just write instead

```
u.x = {2};
X *p = &u.x;
```

Comment: A problem with assigning to `u.x` is that `x` has a `const` member.

Comment: @user7585238 first bracketes for a union, second for a structure. That was noticed earlier.